# What composition of rules make the constructor public Point (double x, double y) => (X, Y) = (x, y) valid?

Tags: c#, lambda, constructor, tuples, deconstructor

The constructor `public Point (double x, double y) => (X, Y) = (x, y);` is obviously valid. But what composition of rules makes it so? It's obviously some combo of tuples, lambdas, and deconstructors, but I don't know exactly what step appears where. For example, I don't know if `(X, Y)` is where it is for a tuple trick or for a lambda trick. Is it possible to break this constructor's inner workings down in to very small steps, such that the exact rules that make it work can be made obvious?

Comment: Expression-bodied functions (`=>`) and [tuple deconstruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/deconstruct).

Comment: By extracting `(X, Y) = (x, y)` into a method and calling that method in the constructor, it may be easier to see that `(X, Y)` belongs to what you call the _tuple trick_ part: [Example fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JThD1Q)

Comment: @AstridE. Feel free to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [@CodeCaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266143/codecaster) in their comment to your original post, **expression-bodied members** and **tuple deconstruction** are the keywords here.

---

Your **constructor**

```
public Point(double x, double y) => (X, Y) = (x, y);
```

is implemented as an [**expression-bodied member**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members), which consists of `member`, `=>` and `expression`, as follows:

```
public Point(double x, double y) => (X, Y) = (x, y);
--------------------------------    ----------------
             member                    expression
```

The *expression-bodied member* implementation is a shorthand version of this:

```
public Point(double x, double y)
{
    (X, Y) = (x, y);
}
```

The **constructor's body**

```
(X, Y) = (x, y);
```

is implemented by using [**tuple deconstruction**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/deconstruct#tuples) to assign the value for properties `X` and `Y`.

The deconstruction can be visualized as follows:

```
(    X     ,     Y    ) = (  x    ,   y   )
 ---------   ---------     ------   ------
 variableA   variableB     valueA   valueB
```

Hence, the constructor body

```
(X, Y) = (x, y);
```

*could* be implemented as follows:

```
X = x;
Y = y;
```

To summarize, your constructor implementation is basically equal to the following:

```
public Point(double x, double y)
{
    X = x;
    Y = y;
}
```

---

As mentioned in my original comment, it may be easier to see that `(X, Y) = (x, y)` belongs to what you call the 'tuple trick' part by extracting `(X, Y) = (x, y)` into a method and calling that method in the constructor:

```
public Point(double x, double y) => SetPoint(x, y);
```

, where `SetPoint()` has several possible implementations:

```
private void SetPoint(double x, double y) => (X, Y) = (x, y);
```

```
private void SetPoint(double x, double y)
{
    (X, Y) = (x, y);
}
```

```
private void SetPoint(double x, double y)
{
    X = x;
    Y = y;
}
```